# Indexed subset iterator in Boost C++

Tags: c++, boost, iterator

My container is random accessible, e.g. std::vector. I need a "indexed subset iterator" of my container. I made up this name. The idea is:

> A subset of my container is given by a set of index, e.g. [0, 4, 5, 7] (size of my container is bigger than 7),  I want an iterator over this subset.

The following is pseudo codes:

```
std::vector<std::string> v = boost::assign::list_of("Aa")("Bb")("Cc")("Dd")("Ee");
std::vector<int> subsetIndex = boost::assign::list_of(0)(2)(3);
IndexedSubsetIterator subsetIterator = IndexedSubsetIterator(v.begin(), subsetIndex);  // or templated version
std::vector<std::string> subset;
boost::push_back(subset ubsetIterator);
```

I am wondering if there is an easy way to do this in STL or boost? Example code please appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what [permutation_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/iterator/doc/permutation_iterator.html) from Boost is for. You construct one from an iterator to the source and an iterator to a index container. Here is a runnable example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/iterator/permutation_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> v =
        boost::assign::list_of("Aa")("Bb")("Cc")("Dd")("Ee");
    std::vector<int> subsetIndex =
        boost::assign::list_of(0)(2)(3);

    auto it_begin =
        boost::make_permutation_iterator(v.begin(), subsetIndex.begin());
    auto it_end =
        boost::make_permutation_iterator(v.end(), subsetIndex.end());

    std::vector<std::string> subset;
    std::copy(it_begin, it_end, std::back_inserter(subset));

    for (const auto& s : subset) std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
Aa
Cc
Dd
```

Comment: exactly what I want. Thank you.